# As select from table only those books which have exactly 4 of the author?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Author:

```
id | name_author
---------
1 | david
2 | kate
3 | tom
4 | mark
```

Table books:

```
id | name_book
------------
1 | book1
2 | book2
3 | book3
```

table relationships authors and books

```
id_book | id_author
-------------------
1 | 2
1 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 2
1 | 1
3 | 4
```

As a result, I has to get the book "Book1" because it has 4 authors (david, kate, tom, mark).

How can I write a query to mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    b.name_book, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name_author) authors
FROM relationships r
JOIN books b ON r.id_book = b.id
JOIN author a ON r.id_author = a.id
GROUP BY r.id_book
HAVING COUNT(r.id_book) = 4
;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could write something like that (not tested)

```
select name_book
from books as b
, link_book_author as l
where b.id = l.id_book
group by name_book
having count(id_author) = 4
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Personally I prefer the JOIN syntax, but I can't see why this won't work.

Comment: just a little note `count(distinct(id_author))` in some cases there is a difference :-)

Comment: I hope the author won't appear twice on the book cover. If he does, we have a case of "ego explosion" :)

Comment: Even then, having a duplicate id_author and book_id would break a key constraint (if those are the only two columns).

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_author)) as authors_num,id_book
FROM table1
GROUP BY id_book
HAVING authors_num=4
```

and if you need book title:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.id_author)) as authors_num,
  table1.id_book, 
  books.name_book
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN books
ON books.id = table1.book_id
GROUP BY id_book
HAVING authors_num=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it:

```
SELECT b.name_book, a.name_author
FROM relationships r
JOIN books b ON r.id_book = b.id
JOIN author a ON r.id_author = a.id
WHERE b.name_book = 'Book1'
;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| name_book | name_author |
+-----------+-------------+
| book1     | kate        |
| book1     | tom         |
| book1     | mark        |
| book1     | david       |
+-----------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or:

```
SELECT b.name_book, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name_author) authors
FROM relationships r
JOIN books b ON r.id_book = b.id
JOIN author a ON r.id_author = a.id
WHERE b.name_book = 'Book1'
;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| name_book | authors             |
+-----------+---------------------+
| book1     | kate,tom,mark,david |
+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```